# Request vs Requests module in Python

Tags: python, request, python-requests

Can anyone tell me what the difference between the `request` and the popular `requests` module is in Python?

Comment: are you referring to request within urllib ?

Answer (score 7):

From the PYPI --> https://pypi.org/project/request/

From Github -- > https://github.com/looking-for-a-job/request.py

It seems like an uncompleted module. Just uninstall it with,

`pip uninstall request`

and then install the requests module with `pip install requests`.

Note: links are dead because the `request` library does not exist anymore.

Comment: dead links, please edit to explain the answer and the information each link should give

Comment: @dangel links are dead because the project `request` does not exist anymore, not in pypi nor in github. Added note to clarify that.

Answer (score 4):

request is the http request and you use it when you writing a code and you want to access the HTTP request data which hit your function, for example request.method or request .user

```
def GetUser(request):
 return request.user
```

requests is library you need to install it, the liverary give your code the ability to act like browser kind of, where your code hit websites and get data from it

```
pip install requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com')
response.status_code
```

this will print out 200 OK